# Why Can't we add id attribute to <img> tag?

Tags: html, css

Whenever We add `id` attribute to the `<img>` tag, the image does not show up.

for eg.

`<img src="something.jpg" id="sidebarAd">`

This Image will not show up. Also, If I Place in it a `<div>` as well. It will not work. For E.g.

```
<div id="sidebarAd">
<img src="something.jpg">
</div>
```

But, if i use a class tag. Everything works like a charm. Why does this happen ?

Comment: [The premise of your question is incorrect](http://jsfiddle.net/b6Sjx/2/).

Comment: The most likely cause I can think of is some sort of AdBlock filter. Try disabling your Ad blocker.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Doesn't show for me :) I use an ad blocker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably caused by an AdBlocker filter responding to your ID name `#sidebarAd`. Which is expected behavior because... Well... It's an ad :)

**[This demo by @zzzzBov](http://jsfiddle.net/b6Sjx/2/)** demonstrates that when my AdBlock Chrome extension is active, the image is invisible, but when disabled, the image is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have a css rule somewhere about that id `#sidebarAd` that sets the element that has it to be invisible..

`display:none` for example

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're using unique ID's, and a closing tag.

Comment: I know this question is closed, but I had this exact issue, and the problem was, indeed, that we didn't have the image closing tag. For once the project worked in IE but NOT in Chrome or Firefox...

Answer (score 0):

Open your developer console (f12 in most browsers) and inspect the element to see if there is some CSS Rule.

Another idea: Since you have the word "ad" in the id, make sure that you don't have an adblock extension enabled.

Comment: No one said he has another element with the same ID, and closing the image tag is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any css associated with that ID that may be hiding it?  Any HTML element can have an ID associated with it, but all ID's must be unique (they can only occur once on each page).